Text matrix with separators
I am trying to write a Python script that:

Reads 2 integers for the width and height of the table using input('?')

Then uses input('?') to read two character strings: one six-character string for the word and one two-character string for the two delimiters

Prints the table (using print()) from the characters of the specified word, with the two separators alternating between the letters

The table has the width and height (number of rows) according to the specified two integers.

The table will be filled with characters from the specified six-character word - these characters will be alternated.

Separators will be between characters, but not after the last character in the row.




For example, if we specify a width of 5, a height of 3, the word 'Python' and the separators '+-', we get the following output:
?5
?3
?Python
?+-
P+y-t+h-o
n+P-y+t-h
o+n-P+y-t

So the problem is that I cannot use list and if else statements for this task. Only cycle for is allowed. I have no idea how to solve it without using indexing.
columns = int(input("?"))
rows = int(input("?"))
word = input("?")
separators = input("?")

separator_index = 0
word_index = 0
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        if word_index < len(word):
            print(word[word_index], end=separators[separator_index])
            word_index += 1
            separator_index = (separator_index + 1) % len(separators)
        else:
            word_index = 0
            print(word[word_index], end=separators[separator_index])
            word_index += 1
            separator_index = (separator_index + 1) % len(separators)
    print()

This is how I solved it, but this version is not allowed for some reasons I described above.

Perhaps using more modulo math is your answer?

One little suggestion to make your life easier.  Separate the parameter prompt into its own function.  Then call the actual work function.  Why???? So you can just hardcode your arguments to call the work code on repeat as you tune it, without driving yourself crazy inputting values ;-)

Your code with which you "solved it" gives wrong output. What's up with that? And what should the output be for width 4?

Aside from the CLI portion, this could be represented as a function:
You just need to loop over the range of the area and concatenate each letter at the modded index along with either a modded separator or new-line (LF).
If you break this out into helper functions, the logic become more obvious.
Note: It does not use if-else conditionals, but it uses a "trick" to coerce a boolean into a 0 or 1 when using the repeat operation.
def word_grid(word, cols, rows, separators):
    """ Generate a grid from 'word', filling a matrix (cols x rows). """
    return ''.join(__next(word, i, cols, separators) for i in range(cols * rows))

def __next(word, index, cols, separators):
    """ Returns the character from 'word' along with either a separator or LF. """
    return __char_at(word, index) + __new_line_or_sep(index, cols, separators)

def __new_line_or_sep(index, cols, separators):
    """ Returns a LF if the current index exceeds the cols, otherwise a separator. """
    return '\n' * __is_last_index(index, cols) or __char_at(separators, index)

def __is_last_index(index, cols):
    """ Checks if the given index is the last index respective of the cols. """
    return index % cols == cols - 1

def __char_at(word, index):
    """ Returns the character from 'word' at a modded position. """
    return word[index % len(word)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(word_grid(word='Python', cols=5, rows=3, separators='+-'))


OK, a bit of a cheat on the separators as I can't just grab one and not print it without advancing the cycle.  This is not apparent on a 2-item separator
Otherwise, use a for / range to know when you're done, which is printing rows * cols characters.  Use modulos on the range's index to track if you need to print either a newline OR a separator.
from itertools import cycle

def do_work(cols : int, rows :int, word : str, separators : str):
        seps = cycle(separators)
        wordchars = cycle(word)
        
        def consume():
            "this is a cheat :-("
            return next(seps)

        def donothing():
            return ""

        #this is a cheat... Python dictionaries can be used to do conditionals/case
        to_consume_or_not_to_consume = {1:consume,0: donothing}

        #print as many characters as required on the basis of grid size
        for ix in range(0,(cols * rows)):

            #line end is the modulo of width. Except at the very first time
            lineend = bool((not(bool(ix % cols)) and ix))
            #you're either printing a line end OR a separator. Except the first time
            notlastsep = ix and not(lineend)

            # debugging... pipe to 2>/dev/null to ignore
            # print(f"{ix=},{lineend=},{notlastsep=}",file=sys.stderr)

            #this is a cheat. because doing next on the separators consumes it to the next one
            print(to_consume_or_not_to_consume[bool(notlastsep)](),end="")
            #line end or separator, order doesnt matter
            print("\n" * lineend,end="")
            #and the cycled character from the word comes after
            print(next(wordchars),end="")

        print()
    

print("""\n\nwanted:\nP+y-t+h-o
n+P-y+t-h
o+n-P+y-t\n\n""")

do_work(5,3,"Python","+-")
print("\n\n\n")
do_work(5,15,"Python","+-*")



which outputs:



wanted:
P+y-t+h-o
n+P-y+t-h
o+n-P+y-t


P+y-t+h-o
n+P-y+t-h
o+n-P+y-t




P+y-t*h+o
n-P*y+t-h
o*n+P-y*t
h+o-n*P+y
t-h*o+n-P
y*t+h-o*n
P+y-t*h+o
n-P*y+t-h
o*n+P-y*t
h+o-n*P+y
t-h*o+n-P
y*t+h-o*n
P+y-t*h+o
n-P*y+t-h
o*n+P-y*t



Instead of using the lookup of functions to call, I can also simulate an IF with boolean short-circuiting:

from itertools import cycle

def do_work(cols : int, rows :int, word : str, separators : str):
        seps = cycle(separators)
        wordchars = cycle(word)
        
        for ix in range(0,(cols * rows)):
            lineend = bool((not(bool(ix % cols)) and ix))
            notlastsep = ix and not(lineend)

            #only thing that changed...
            notlastsep and print(next(seps),end="")
            print("\n" * lineend,end="")
            print(next(wordchars),end="")

        print()
    

This had the exact same results as before.  That's because boolean-shortcircuiting knows the and will still evaluate to false if notlastsep is False, so it doesn't bother calling the function, hence no cycling of separators.

You can think of the output as joining by newlines a height number of rows over a cycle of the characters of word sliced to width characters per row, each zipped with an empty-string-padded cycle of the delimiters:
from itertools import chain, cycle, islice

def text_matrix(width, height, word, delimiters):
    word = cycle(word)
    return '\n'.join(
        ''.join(
            chain.from_iterable(
                zip(chain(('',), cycle(delimiters)), islice(word, width))
            )
        )
        for _ in range(height)
    )

so that:
print(text_matrix(5, 3, 'Python', '+-'))

outputs:
P+y-t+h-o
n+P-y+t-h
o+n-P+y-t

Demo: https://ideone.com/EAx8JO

May be you can generate total words and separators first, and then you can iterate words and separators at the same time with iterator:
def words_to_iter(words, iter_len):
    n = len(words)
    word_nums = iter_len // n + ((iter_len % n) > 0 ) * 1
    return (words * word_nums)[:iter_len]

m = columns * rows
iter_words = words_to_iter(word, m)
iter_separators = words_to_iter(separators, len(iter_words)-1)

def iter_string(s):
    for i in s:
        yield i
    
count = 0
iter_sp = iter_string(iter_separators)
for i in iter_words:
    end = ((count + 1) % columns == 0) * "\n" or next(iter_sp)
    print(i, end=end)
    count += 1

